# How do i iterate through a directory, and print out the file names and their sizes and make the printout clean looking?

Tags: python, list, directory

The code i am currently working on, enters a directory. Once in that directory I need to iterate through the files in that directory and print the file names and extensions, along with the file size.

```
os.chdir(Path('pets', 'cats'))

current = Path.cwd()
for file in os.listdir(current):
    fileName = os.path.split(file)
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(file)
    print(str(fileName) + ': ' + str(fileSize))
```

The issue I am having is that the printout includes ('' '<filename.ext>'). I want to omit all these extra characters and just have <filename.ext>. Any clues on how I can clean this up?

Comment: You can use `fileName = os.path.basename(file)` instead of `fileName = os.path.split(file)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `pathlib` module, so you can write:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('dogs', 'cats')
for item in path.iterdir():
    if not item.is_file():
      continue

    fstat = os.stat(item)
    print(f'{item.name}: {fstat.st_size}')
```

This would yield output like:

```
foo.txt: 32
bar.txt: 64
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this piece of code for the task:

```
import glob
import os

folPath = r'dir_address'

for fPath in glob.glob("{0}\**\*".format(folPath), recursive=True):

# get file size

    fSize = os.stat(fPath).st_size/1024
    print('size of {0} is {1}'.format(fPath, fSize))
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: As written this isn't valid Python. You need to fix the indentation and you need to uncomment the `import` lines. Also consider using f-strings rather than the `.format` method.